# accessing catalog data from magento SOAP through android

Tags: android, magento

I m developing an app (android) for a ecommerce company and in need for accessing the online magento database for their catalog through an android app. So please guide me a way for the solution and also provide suitable tutorials if u find any because i didnt get any tutorail.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

Comment: thanks tim
but as i m a novice i need some detail about how to implement. Actually i know how everything works but i didnt understand how to implement the code works

Comment: http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_api